# How to execute a NodeJs script in azure-scm-console, having canvas-data-cli command

Tags: node.js, canvas, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm executing a code file form azure scm console with node . It give the error: "'canvasDataCli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I can run the canvasDataCli sync command directly from console successfully as:

> canvasDataCli sync -c ./config.js

Here is the code file, test.js

```
   var Promise = require('promise');

   require('canvas-data-cli');

   var s='./config.js';
   var command=`canvasDataCli sync -c  ${s}`;

   function exec_command_promise(cmd) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child_process = exec(cmd);

    // event : stdout
    child_process.stdout.on('data', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    // event : stderr
    child_process.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.log(data);
        reject(data);
    });

    // event : close
    child_process.on('close', data => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
    });

   }); 
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing the same package at global scope i.e., canvas-data-cli at

my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugConsole

> npm install canvas-data-cli -g

I think the issue was that, canvasDataCli sync command create a new process, which was being run at my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/ and I was executing it from

my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install `canvasDataCli` to my KUDU site, if just run canvasDataCli it will show  `not recognized` like yours, this is because the PATH doesn't contain the variable.

So if you want to use `canvasDataCli` you need to set the PATH , you could use `set PATH=D:\local\AppData\npm;%PATH%`, then check if the variable was set with `which canvasDataCli`. If success, it will show `/d/local/AppData/npm/canvasDataCli`.

However this is a temporary variable, you could also set it as permanent variable with `applicationHost.xdt` file. You need put it under `d:\home\site\`.

Here is `applicationHost.xdt` content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
 <system.webServer> 
  <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
   <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <add name="PATH" value="D:\local\AppData\npm;%PATH%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" 
    xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
   </environmentVariables>
  </runtime> 
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

But if you want to use this way , you need set the environment variable firstly then install canvas-data-cli. Or it will delete all files under `D:\local\AppData\npm`.

After this you should be able to run code , however the code you upload seems to have some problem. [image]

Is it because of some files missing in my folders. Maybe you will success in you environment.

**Prevent error**：you better upgrade you node version, you could go to Application settings in portal, add the setting `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` with the value `8.8.1` or other version you want.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: @Muhammad Umar Farooq if my answer works,, you could mark my answer.Thanks!